# concatenating and saving multiple pair of CSV in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in python. I have a hundred pair of CSV file. The file looks like this:

```
25_13oct_speed_0.csv    
26_13oct_speed_0.csv
25_13oct_speed_0.1.csv
26_13oct_speed_0.1.csv
25_13oct_speed_0.2.csv
26_13oct_speed_0.2.csv
and others
```

I want to concatenate the pair files between 25 and 26 file. each pair of the file has a speed threshold (Speed_0, 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.0) which is labeled on the file name. These files have the same structure data.

```
Mac Annotation  X   Y
A   first       0   0
A   last        0   0
B   first       0   0
B   last        0   0
```

Therefore, concatenate analyze is enough to join these two data. I use this method:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('25_13oct_speed_0.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('26_13oct_speed_0.csv')
frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

for each pair files. but it takes time and not an elegant way. is there a good way to combine automatically the pair file and save simultaneously?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Conceptually, you may be able to extract the key elements you are trying to match by (`25/26` and `0/0.1/0.2/etc.`), create a key based on those, sort the .csv names by that key, and then iterate over those to read in and concatenate like pairs of dataframes.

Comment: thank you @BrendanCox, I will try to make a key based on the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create DataFrame by list of files and add 2 new columns by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by first `_`:

```
print (files)
['25_13oct_speed_0.csv', '26_13oct_speed_0.csv', 
 '25_13oct_speed_0.1.csv', '26_13oct_speed_0.1.csv', 
 '25_13oct_speed_0.2.csv', '26_13oct_speed_0.2.csv']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'files': files})
df1[['g','names']] = df1['files'].str.split('_', n=1, expand=True)
print (df1)
                    files   g                names
0    25_13oct_speed_0.csv  25    13oct_speed_0.csv
1    26_13oct_speed_0.csv  26    13oct_speed_0.csv
2  25_13oct_speed_0.1.csv  25  13oct_speed_0.1.csv
3  26_13oct_speed_0.1.csv  26  13oct_speed_0.1.csv
4  25_13oct_speed_0.2.csv  25  13oct_speed_0.2.csv
5  26_13oct_speed_0.2.csv  26  13oct_speed_0.2.csv
```

Then loop per groups per column `names`, loop by groups with [`DataFrame.itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) and create new DataFrame with `read_csv`, if necessary add new column filled by values from `g`, append to list, `concat` and last cave to new file by name from column `names`:

```
for i, g in df1.groupby('names'):
    out = []
    for n in g.itertuples():
        df = pd.read_csv(n.files).assign(source=n.g)
        out.append(df)
    dfbig = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True)
    print (dfbig)
    dfbig.to_csv(g['names'].iat[0])
```

Comment: thank you very much, this answer is very helpful for the next step of my work. pardon me, out means a dictionary?

Comment: out is list, first empty and then filled by dataframes.