# glob Multiple CSV and np.arange

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in python. I have some problem with loop `glob.glob` and `np.arrange` loop.

I have a hundred CSV files looks like this:

```
13oct_speed_1kmh.csv
13oct_speed_2kmh.csv
and others
```

The structure data of all files look like this:

```
Distance ID
2.14     A
82.12    B
12.45    A
21.07    B
11.42    A
```

I want to eliminate the distance based on the buffer zone:

```
np.arange(10,100,30)
array([10, 40, 70])
```

I used this code:

```
def buffer (value, threshold):
    return (value < threshold)
files = glob.glob("13oct_speed_*.csv") 
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    for i in np.arange(10,100,30):
        threshold = i
        result_df = df[buffer(df["Distance"], threshold)]
        csvFileName = f + 'Buffer_' + str(threshold) + ".csv"
        result_df.to_csv(csvFileName, sep=",")
```

but the result is very weird because the loop never stops (always saving the new file).

My desire output is every distance column file eliminated based on buffer threshold.

My expected output looks like this:

```
13oct_speed_1kmh_buffer10.csv
13oct_speed_1kmh_buffer40.csv
13oct_speed_1kmh_buffer70.csv
13oct_speed_2kmh_buffer10.csv
13oct_speed_2kmh_buffer40.csv
13oct_speed_2kmh_buffer70.csv
```

how to fix it? thank you

Comment: How working `result_df = df[df["Distance"] < threshold]` ?

Comment: thank you, perfect. Therefore, no need to make a definition about buffer?

Comment: no, not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit helper function and change `csvFileName` with `format` for expected output, filename with extension is returned by [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
import os

files = glob.glob("csv/13oct_speed_*.csv") 
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    for threshold in np.arange(10,100,30):
        result_df = df[df["Distance"] < threshold]
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(f)
        csvFileName = "{}_Buffer{}{}".format(name, threshold, extension)
        print (csvFileName)
        result_df.to_csv(csvFileName)
```

Comment: thank you. perfect. even the file name does not include .csv in the middle again

Comment: If you have time, I got stuck on this problem. Would you mind seeing my question this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56703842/concatenating-and-saving-multiple-pair-of-csv-in-pandas?noredirect=1#comment99977047_56703842